# Can I instantiate classes containing values with side effects at the top level?

Tags: class, f#, side-effects

This question is related to and overlaps with the question in [Should one wrap type providers containing values that have side effects inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528864/should-one-wrap-type-providers-containing-values-that-have-side-effects-inside-a), kindly answered by `Aaron M. Eshbach`.

I am trying to implement in my code the excellent advice in the `F# coding conventions` page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/conventions.

The section `Use classes to contain values that have side effects` is particularly interesting. It says

```
There are many times when initializing a value can have side effects, such as instantiating a context to a database or other remote resource. It is tempting to initialize such things in a module and use it in subsequent functions.
```

and provides an example. Then it points out three problems with this practice (I omit those for lack of space, but they can be seen at the linked article) and recommends using a simple class to hold dependencies.

Foolowing on that advice I implemented a simple class to contain a value that has side effects:

```
type Roots() =
    let msg = "Roots: Computer must be one of THREADRIPPER, LAPTOP or HPW8"

    member this.dropboxRoot =
        let computerName = Environment.MachineName 
        match computerName with
        | "THREADRIPPER" -> @"C:\"
        | "HP-LAPTOP" -> @"C:\"
        | "HPW8" -> @"H:\"
        | _ -> failwith msg
```

Then I can use it inside a function

```
let foo (name: string) =
    let roots = Roots()
    let path = Path.Combine(roots.dropboxRoot,  @"Dropbox\Temp\" + name + ".csv")
    printfn "%s" path

foo "SomeName"
```

So far so good. In the example above the class is quite "light" and I can instantiate it inside any function.

However, the class containing the values with side effects could as well be computationally intensive. In that case I would like to instantiate it only once and call it from different functions:

```
let roots = Roots()

let csvPrinter (name: string) =
    let path = Path.Combine(roots.dropboxRoot,  @"Dropbox\Folder1\" + name + ".csv")
    printfn "%s" path

let xlsxPrinter (name: string) =
    let path = Path.Combine(roots.dropboxRoot,  @"Dropbox\Folder2\" + name + ".xlsx")
    printfn "%s" path

csvPrinter "SomeName"
xlsxPrinter "AnotherName"
```

So my question is: if I instantiate the class `Roots` at the top level in a module am I defeating the purpose of creating a class, which was to avoid the problems described in the `F# coding conventions` page? If that is the case, how do I deal with computationally intensive definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is - yes, that defeats the purpose of having this sort of wrapper in the first place.

The guideline however misses the forest for the trees a bit - the real problem there is a more fundamental question of managing stateful dependencies and external data in an environment that advocates function purity and referential transparency, especially when you're looking at a large codebase that needs to grow and change over time (if we're looking at one-off throwaway scripts, just do what gets the job done). It is more in the way how the `roots` field is populated and consumed (as a hardcoded, static dependency), then whether the value there is wrapped in a class or not.

The approach I would recommend here is to write your business logic as a module (or multiple modules) of pure functions, and pass dependencies explicitly as arguments. This way, you defer making decisions about the dependencies to the caller. This may go all the way up, to the entry point of your program (the main function in a console application, the `Startup` class in an API and so on). In the dreaded OOP parlance, what you're looking at is the equivalent of a composition root - the one place in your program where you assemble your dependencies.

This may involve having a class wrapper around an otherwise purely functional module, as the convention you link to suggests, but that's not a foregone conclusion. You may very well have one (side-effecting) function to produce the value for you, and you may just pass this one single value down.

```
let getDropboxRoot () : string option = 
    let computerName = Environment.MachineName 
    match computerName with
    | "THREADRIPPER" -> Some @"C:\"
    | "HP-LAPTOP" -> Some @"C:\"
    | "HPW8" -> Some @"H:\"
    | _ -> None        

let csvPrinter (dropboxRoot: string) (name: string) =
    let path = Path.Combine(dropboxRoot,  @"Dropbox\Folder1\" + name + ".csv")
    printfn "%s" path
```

This way you have a full control over your effectful operation - you can call the function whenever you want, and you can call it again for a new value if the environment changes. The rest of the code does neither know or care that the value you feed in comes from an effectful operation - it makes reasoning about what it does, as well as testing, simple.

Having a class wrapper around it adds nothing to those properties by itself. It might provide a nicer API for a bit more boilerplate, but the real problem that is being discussed there is elsewhere.